# Django - Can't fetch Json data in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

Hello I am pretty new to Django and Javascript I want to build a simple application where users can write posts and see a list of all posts in reverse chronologial order on the index page. (The index page is rendered fine.)

I created some Posts via the admin interface.
Unfortunately I can't figure out why I am not able to fetch the JsonResponse and no div gets append to my template.

the code looks as following:

first I've created a Posts model

```
    class Posts(models.Model):
        text = models.TextField(max_length=512)
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
        def serialize(self):
            return {
                "id": self.id,
                "text": self.text,
                "timestamp": self.timestamp.strftime("%b %d %Y, %I:%M %p"),
            }
```

My view function to get all posts from the datatbase is called via

```
    path("get_posts", views.get_posts, name="get_posts"),
```

and looks like this:

```
    def get_posts():

         # get all posts
        posts = Posts.objects.all()

        # Return posts in reverse chronologial order
        posts = posts.order_by("-timestamp").all()
        return JsonResponse([post.serialize() for post in posts], safe=False)
```

In my Javascript file (index.js) I want to load all Posts, create a div for each post and append them to my template

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

      // By default, load_posts
      load_posts();
      });

    function load_posts() {

      // get posts from /posts API Route
      fetch('/get_posts')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(posts => {

        // create a div element for each post
        posts.forEach(post => {
            let div = document.createElement('div');
            div.className = "post-item row";
            div.innerHTML = `
            <span class="col"> <b>${post['text']}</b> </span>
            `;
            // append div to posts-view
            document.querySelector('#posts-view').append(div);
        });
      });
    }
```

my template index.html

```
    {% load static %}

    {% block body %}
        <div id="posts-view">
        </div>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block script %}
        <script src="{% static 'network/index.js' %}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
```

I imported the required library to my views.py

```
    from django.http import JsonResponse
```

I imported the Posts model

```
    from .models import Posts
```

I checked all variable and function names more than twice...

Edit:

When checking the path manually I get a TypeError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "D:\Network\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 56, in inner
    response = get_response(request)   
File "D:\Network\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /get_posts Exception Value: get_posts() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

In the browser console I see two errors.

```
index.js:10          
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_posts 500 (Internal Server Error)
load_posts  @   index.js:10
(anonymous) @   index.js:4
```

and

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
Promise.then (async)
load_posts @ index.js:12
(anonymous) @ index.js:4
```

Comment: Do you see the correct JSON results when you check `/get_posts` path manually? Have you checked the browser's console for JS error messages?

Comment: I put all the errors at the end of my post under Edit. I Don't really understand what these mean. imo I did not pass an argument to get_posts()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Django [view function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/views/) takes an [`HttpRequest` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest) as its first parameter, which is missing from your view function definiton:

```
def get_posts(request):
    ...
```

The JS `fetch()` call try to parse the returned Django error message as a JSON object. You can add [error-checking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful) to that.

Comment: Oh, alright. Thank you! I never red the documentation about views. I thought I don't need the HttpRequest object, because it isn't red in the function.